# How to invoke the static constructors in LINQ and sort elements by a static property?

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

Here are the simplified classes what I would like to store and sort in descending order by the static Area property

```
abstract class Top { }

abstract class Top<T> : Top
{
    public static int Area { get; protected set; }
}    

abstract class Middle1 : Top<Middle1>
{
    static Middle1()
    {
        Area = 1;
    }
}

//sealed classes inherited from Middle1

abstract class Middle2 : Top<Middle2>
{
    static Middle2()
    {
        Area = 2;
    }
}

//sealed classes inherited from Middle2
```

And the LINQ query what I used.

```
var array = from type in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().DefinedTypes
           where 
               type.IsSealed &&
               type.BaseType != typeof(Object) &&
               type.BaseType != typeof(Enum)
           orderby type.Name
           group type by type.BaseType;

    foreach (var item in array)
       item.Key.TypeInitializer.Invoke(null, null);

    array = array.OrderByDescending(x => x.Key.GetProperty("Area",
       BindingFlags.Public | 
       BindingFlags.Static | 
       BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy)
       .GetValue(null, null));
```

I would like to make these 3 steps into 1 statement.

Comment: LINQ is for querying, not for side-effects.

Comment: "I would like to make these 3 steps into 1 statement." - why?

Comment: @AakashM Because I'm novice and interested about it.

Comment: Have you considered making `Area` a custom `Attribute` applied to the class?  It would allow you to sort on the `Type` without having to call the `TypeInitializer`.  If you need access to it as a property,  you can use both (and keep them in sync), or have the property return the `Attribute` value (but this is slightly less efficient).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't be possible. 
The foreach loop is your problem here - it does something with all entries in your array (i.e. invoke the type initializer), but it does not return anything that you may continue to work with in your LINQ statement.
You might write a custom extension method for IEnumerable like this

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MyForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumeration, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach(T item in enumeration)
    {
        action(item);
    }
    return enumeration;
}
```

This is however not in the spirit of LINQ - I do not recommend using code like this (LINQ should be side-effect free!).
Then you could write your statement like

```
    var array = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().DefinedTypes.Where(type => type.IsSealed &&
                                                                           type.BaseType != typeof (Object) &&
                                                                           type.BaseType != typeof (Enum))
        .OrderBy(type => type.Name)
        .GroupBy(type => type.BaseType)
        .MyForEach(x => x.Key.TypeInitializer.Invoke(null, null))
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Key.GetProperty("Area",
            BindingFlags.Public |
            BindingFlags.Static |
            BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy)
       .GetValue(null, null));
```

... but I don't see the point here. It does not make the code more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of using the custom `Attribute` suggestion I made in the comments of your question ([LINQPad file](http://share.linqpad.net/i9bue9.linq)).  There are some notes in the code comments.

```
void Main()
{
    var array = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().DefinedTypes
        .Where(t => t.IsSealed &&
            t.BaseType != typeof(object) &&
            t.BaseType != typeof(Enum))
        .OrderBy(t => t.Name)
        .GroupBy(t => t.BaseType)
        .OrderByDescending(a => a.Key.GetCustomAttribute<AreaAttribute>().Value);

    array.Dump();
}

abstract class Top { }

abstract class Top<T> : Top
{
    //If you want to have the Area property available on sub-class instances, uncomment this line.
    //public int Area=> this.GetType().GetCustomAttribute<AreaAttribute>().Value;
}

[Area(1)]
abstract class Middle1 : Top<Middle1>
{
}
sealed class M1Sub1 : Middle1 { }
sealed class M1Sub2 : Middle1 { }
sealed class M1Sub3 : Middle1 { }

[Area(2)]
abstract class Middle2 : Top<Middle2>
{
}
sealed class M2Sub1 : Middle2 { }
sealed class M2Sub2 : Middle2 { }
sealed class M2Sub3 : Middle2 { }

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class AreaAttribute : Attribute
{
    public AreaAttribute(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public int Value { get; }
}
```

---

It produces the following output:

[image]

Comment: I accepted the other answer, because that was the real answer for the explicit question. I really like your solution, I dig myself into the Attributes a little bit, probably I will continue this way my project.